# Convertir a int todas las listas dentro de una lista Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Necesito cambiar a `int` todos los elementos de una lista en Python 3.
Ejemplo:

Esta es la lista original:

```
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9'], ['10', '11', '12', '13']]
```

Quiero que me quede:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

Mi código tiene una primera entrada que consiste en el número de elementos de la lista separda por espacios

```
q = int(input())
miList = []
for i in range(q):
    miList.append(input().split())

print("Esta es la lista original ",miList)
```

Comment: Hola Nico, ¿puedes poner el código de lo que has intentado hasta ahora para ver dónde te falla?

Comment: Normalmente pedimos ver los intentos anteriores y los fallos en tu codigo para poder dar una respuesta más adecuada. Tambien nos aseguramos así que no estamos respondiendo ejercicios de texto. Tu pregunta tiene varias soluciones posibles, unas más eficientes y otras más didacticas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Convertir a enteros la lista dentro del for loop, anidando otro:

(El método `.split()` devuelve una lista, así que tienes que iterar sobre ella antes)

```
q = int(input("Cuantas listas?: "))

miList = []
lista_enteros = []

for i in range(q):
    lista_nums = []
    miList = input("Numeros separados por espacio: ").split()

    for nums in miList:
        lista_nums.append(int(nums))

    lista_enteros.append(lista_nums)

print("Esta es la lista de numeros enteros: ", lista_enteros)
```

2. Con comprensiones de lista:

Asumiendo `miList` como tu lista de listas:

```
lista_enteros = [[int(elem) for elem in lista] for lista in miList]
```

Las comprensiones de listas en python son una de las maneras más aceptadas de modificar y manipular listas. Tienes que leerlo de derecha a izquierda:

1. Desempaquetas cada uno de los elementos de `miList` en la variable
   `lista`.
2. Desempaquetas los `elem`entos de la variable `lista` y los
   añades cada uno a la nueva lista `lista_enteros` convirtiéndolos
   primero a `int()`

Alguna duda con las comprensiones de lista pregunta y lo intento explicar mejor

#### #EDIT:

Para mostrar y exagerar todavía más la utilidad de las compresiones de lista hay una manera de sobrecargar el concepto y realizar todo el problema en una misma cadena de instrucciones (AVISO: no es la mejor forma de aprenderlo, es solo una exageración):

```
miList = [
    [int(n) for n in input("Numeros separados por espacio: ").split()]
    for i in range(int(input("Cuantas listas?: ")))
]

f"Esta es la lista de enteros: {miList}"
```

(Los `f strings` son una nueva manera de imprimir variables en consola que equivalen a `print("texto {variable}".format(variable))`)